# PHP, MySQL and Cron Jobs - Does a query store all rows to start, or go through sequentially?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a MySQL table:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Status
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  1
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  2
etc
```

It is important that the table have the most up-to-date information in it, and so a cron job is run every minute, to update the table.

The `Status` column is to store whether the row needs to be updated, or is currently being updated. If the row needs to be updated, the status is 0. If the row is currently being updated, the status is 1. If the row has already been updated, the status is 2.

Once all rows have a status of 2, they are all reset to 0, and the process starts over.

The cron job runs every minute, but sometimes updating a row might take multiple minutes, meaning multiple cron jobs will be running simultaneously.

My question is, if I have a query like:

```
UPDATE * FROM table WHERE status=0
```

does the query go through one at a time, to the next 0? Or does the query look at all the rows first, and store which ones it will eventually visit?

**EXAMPLE**

Say that the following table is set up:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Status
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
```

At t=0, the first cron job (cj1) begins. It enters the first row, and sets the status to 1.

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Status
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  1
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
```

This process takes more than a minute, and so a second cron job (cj2) begins at t=1m.

cj2 sees that the first row is already being updated, and so goes to the second row.

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Status
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  1
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  1
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
 ...  |  ...  |  ...  |  0
```

Let's say that cj2 is busy updating that row for a few minutes. When cj1 finishes with the first row, will it skip to the 3rd row, because it sees that row 2 has a status of 1? Or will cj2 go to the second row, because it initially had a status of 0 when the query was called?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design.  If a cron job hasn't finished, then another should not begin.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what would you recommend then? The table needs to be as close to current as possible. The cron job is checking other pages, to see if anything has been updated on them, and updated the table if required. Having only one cron job running at a time, where each row update could take anywhere from a couple seconds to a couple minutes, will not suffice. Especially if the table has multiple tens of thousands of rows, then it could potentially be days before a single process could make it to the end of the table.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB? The behavior depends on whether you're using an engine that supports transactions, because a single query is essentially a transaction.

Comment: @Barmar I have it set as InnoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using InnoDB, each query will be performed as a transaction by default. So when you do

```
UPDATE table
SET <whatever>
WHERE status = 0
```

it will lock all the rows that match the `status` value. Other processes that perform a similar query will be blocked if they try to access any of these rows.

The specific way that it does this depends on whether there's an index on the `status` column. If there is, it simply locks that index entry and then updates all the rows it refers to.

If there's no index, it will have to step through the database sequentially. Whenever it encouters a row with `status = 0` it will lock that row and then update it. Other clients may scan the database in a different order, so they might see the rows that this query will update before it gets to it. If they upate the `status` at the same time as they update other columns, then you shouldn't have a problem, because when this process reaches those rows they won't match the `status = 0` criteria any more.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation how you have implemented. If finished updating a row.. a cron job go and fetch next 1 result to be updated (status=0) and process that only one record you can achieve your desired goal.

If you will fetch all results with status=0 and store then into $resuls variable and start a loop on it then cron job 1 will reprocess record 2 without knowing that cron 2 already did processed because $result variable is not having updated information.

Comment: There's no loop in his code, it just performs the `UPDATE` query that he showed in the question.